# Handle empty cell in excel - Error in converting empty cell to Datetime

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read an excel file, and one column is a date field. I am able to get those values and store to a variable. But some cells are empty which gives an error " The best-overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.FromOADate(double)' has some invalid arguments'" . Below is my code:

```
 BeginDate = DateTime.FromOADate((range.Cells[2, 8] as Excel.Range).Value2);
```

(cell [2,8] is empty so it gives this error.) If it is empty I want null ( or somehow I need to catch the empty cell.) How to fix this?

Comment: Why not check if the cell is empty?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including how `BeginDate` is declared.

Comment: excel-vba tag doesn't seems relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var value = (range.Cells[2, 8] as Excel.Range).Value2;
if (value != null)
     BeginDate = DateTime.FromOADate(value);
```